# Setting evars in DTM

Tags: adobe, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to set an evar in DTM but nothing is actually firing.  I am trying to capture the user id that is set in a data layer using evar5 and am trying to pass it in a page load rule, but I don't see anything in the debugger tool or adobe report suite.

Attached is a screenshot showing how I am setting the evar, any advice on why this may not be working?

[image: setting evar in dtm]

Comment: Do you have a data element named `user id`? Do you see the load rule firing whenever you run debug mode (`_satellite.setDebug(true);`)?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you should try:

Check if the page load rule where in you have defined the above is executing or not ? Either type `_satellite.setDebug(true);` in browser console before you load the page or use Adobe DTM switch browser plugin.

If rule is executing, check if userid data element is receiving any value. Type  `_satellite.getVar('user id');` in the console and check.

If rule is not executing, debug the page load rule condition in the browser console after putting checkpoints in the satellite JS rendering on the page.

These steps will make you reach closer to the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't published the rule, Make sure the page you are on is loading the staging library or make sure you tell the page to load it.

```
localStorage.setItem('sdsat_stagingLibrary',true);
```

Then refresh the page.